# Divs not lining up

Tags: html, css

I have a news section for my website, and I have some problems with article divs not lining up. The picture of what I'm talking about can be seen here:

http://postimg.org/image/euv81w6jp/

There should be 3 articles on a row and as you can see the middle one only has one, and the other two are below when they should be on the same line.

I have a wrapper that holds all articles with the following css:

```
.sec-news {
   width: 71.264367816%;
   float: right;
```

And each article has 4 divs inside (date, title, picture, excerpt) is contained in a div with the following css:

```
.sec-news .article {
   width: 32%;
   margin-right: 2%;
```

The wrapper is floated to the right because I have another section floated to the left. Please help me out.

Comment: Yeah use floating point that will be really precise.

Comment: Please provide your html as well.

Answer (score 3):

While I can't explain the behaviour itself, here's a hint:

`(32 + 2) * 3 = 102`... `102 > 100` so how do you expect it to fit? ;)

Comment: I tried lowering the values down to 20% that doesn't help either

Comment: And how come there's only one that doesn't lign up?